# How to fix library package exception when site is deployed via Azure DevOps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have created a common project where I define partials and view components, and then use them inside of an MVC web project.
Both projects are running in .net core 2.2.

However when I deploy the web project to an app service via Azure Devops, I receive an invalid operation exception.

I followed this post to get this to work, and the works fine when I run the site locally.
https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2017/07/21/asp-net-core-mvc-common-components-view-across-applications/

The error appears intermittently, I have had the site work fine for a few hours, and then suddenly it will stop working when I publish the site again and continue to not work for hours/days.
I cannot identify what causes this.
I have released an older build that previously did not work, it would then work without issue, and vice versa.

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource'
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List<string> assemblies)

InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource'
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List<string> assemblies)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart+<>c.<GetReferencePaths>b__8_0(CompilationLibrary library)
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature<TFeature>(TFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorProjectEngine.ProcessCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Process(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(string normalizedPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet<IChangeToken> expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromPath(string executingFilePath, string pagePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetView(string executingFilePath, string viewPath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.GetView(string executingFilePath, string viewPath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialCoreAsync(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TextWriter writer)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.PartialAsync(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.Partial(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.Partial(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName)
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<TFilter, TFilterAsync>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

This package does exist in both the common project, and in the web project.

The error will only appear when I try to use a partial or view component from the html, whereas if I just have the common project referenced but don't try to use it, it does not throw the exception.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening but something you can use to debug this would be Azure Kudu. Navigate to https://*****.scm.azurewebsites.net where ***** is the name of your Web App to view what's actually present on your file system. You can also enable more detailed logs and investigate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have looked into Kudu and can see in my site/wwwroot directory there is no System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll. I have confirmed the package is referenced. `<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="4.5.1" />`

Comment: How do you do your deployment through Azure DevOps? Do you use a Web Deploy package?

Comment: Yes. /p:WebPublishMethod=Package

Comment: We have figured out the issue.
Adding the following to the csproj file has fixed all errors and I can now load partials in the project:


`<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>`

Thanks for your help with this